# Is there a way to use the first version python interpreter

Tags: python

is there a way to download the very first version python. Can you please provide a link
I am trying to search for it. And am unable to find it I need it for educational purposes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get all python versions from the python website. Here is a link to download python version 1.6.1
https://www.python.org/download/releases/1.6.1/